# Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': <nativehr>0x80070002</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>

Tags: 2010, development, error, event-receivers, feature-receiver

I have a feature. On the `FeatureActivated` event I am creating a list if it is not there. I also have an EventReceiver that in the elements.xml on the Receivers node  has the attribute `ListUrl`. This is set to the URL that I create in the `FeatureActivated` event.

When I deploy my code through Visual Studio I am getting:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': 0x80070002

I am presuming that it has something to do with the order the code is run. The Event Receiver is being "installed" before the list is being created.

Is there a way I can get round this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As EStruyf said, you can change the deployment configuration and debug the code for your Feature Event Receivers. But, you can also attach the event receivers after making sure List is created, so put this code after your list is created.

```
public class Feature1EventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
    {

 public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
      {
        SPList lst = site.Lists["ListName"];   
        string asmName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;  //get the Full Assembly Name 
        string itemReceiverName = "Project1.EventReceivers"; // Event Receivers class (EventReceivers.cs) which contains definitions for events for e.g. ItemAdded...
        lst.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdded, asmName, itemReceiverName);   

    }
    //delete the event receivers on Feature de-activation
        public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            SPWeb oWeb = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;

            SPList oList = oWeb.Lists[_listName];
            for (int i = oList.EventReceivers.Count - 1; i >=0 ; i--)
            {
                if (oList.EventReceivers[i].Type.Equals(SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdded))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        oList.EventReceivers[i].Delete();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        // Write to logs
                    }
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Your EventReceivers.cs will look like

```
class EventReceivers : SPItemEventReceiver
    {

        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            if (properties.Context != null)
            {
                try
                {

                  //do something here
                }
                catch { return; }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Will give it a go

Comment: why don't you do it in one Feature?

Comment: I get the System.IO.FileNotFoundException error. Not tried your method yet need to work out AssemblyofEventHandler & YourPublicKeyToken

Comment: Ask questions, if you have any doubts

Comment: Where would I find the information for asmName? Do you still need the elements.xml for the reciever?

Comment: You need to pass the Full Assembly Name and Event Receiver class (class which contains definitions of events). See my update response.

Comment: You don't need now the Elements.xml of receiver since now you are attaching event handlers using the Object model. See more different ways you can bind event handlers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407249

Comment: it can ealso be done using the Feature dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

A quick way is to set the value of the active deployment configuration from **Default** to **No Activation** (in the properties of the project). That way you need to manually activate your features and you can directly see what goes wrong.

Comment: System.IO.FileNotFoundException = Not creating the list before the event handler is added

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
http://sharepointfundamental.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/sharepoint-2010-error-occurred-in-deployment-step-activate-features-0x80070002/

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/sharepoint2010programming/thread/54f95e2b-782e-4205-85c6-dc0074bf8563

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: http://sharepointfundamental.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/sharepoint-2010-error-occurred-in-deployment-step-activate-features-0x80070002/ This solves my problem. In my case the SiteURL was not set correct. The list doesn't exist in the SiteURL I set. Thanks Zakir HC for the reference link. Regards,
Khushi

Answer (score 0):

I have split the code into two features. One creates the list the other adds the event reciever.  I have put a feature depencey that the event reciever featute needs the setup feature enabled.

Not ideal but works. Would like  to try and do it all in one feature.

Comment: having such dumb logic in couple of features would further complicate deployment process. keep it in one.